# Kafka Avro deserializer with local schema file

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro, confluent-schema-registry

Background :
I used SpringKafka to implement Avro based Consumer and Producer. Other important components : Kafka-Broker, Zookeeper and Schema-registry runs in a docker container. And this works perfectly fine for me.

What I Want :
I want to have a Kafka Avro Deserializer(in Consumer) which should be independent of schema-registry. In my case, I have a avroSchema file which would not change. So I want to get rid of this additional step of using schema-registry on Consumer side and Rather go for a local schema file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Producer serializer uses the Schema Registry, then the Consumer should as well. Avro *requires* you to have a reader **and** writer schema.

If the consumer, for whatever reason cannot access the Registry over the network, you would need to use `ByteArrayDeserializer`, then you would take the byte-slice after position 5 (`0x0` + 4 byte schema integer ID) of the `byte[]` from the part of the record you want to  parse.

Then, from Avro API, you can use `GenericDatumReader` along with your local `Schema` reference to get a `GenericRecord` instance, but this would *assume* your reader and writer schema are the exact same (but this shouldn't be true, as the producer could change the schema at any time).

---

Or you can create a SpecificRecord from the schema you have, and configure the `KafkaAvroDeserializer` to use that.